How do I create a solution for an existing C project in Visual Studio?
I have an existing program (the SM64 decompilation) that was written in C and is built using a makefile. I have this program opened in Visual Studio 2022 as a folder. Currently when I want to make a new build, I need to open the command line and enter my build commands manually. I want to create a .sln solution file for this project so I can configure it to build directly from Visual Studio.
Visual Studio has an option to create a project from existing code, but it only supports Visual C++, Visual Basic, and C#. How can I create a Visual Studio solution file for an existing C project?

I think you might get away with pretending that the source code is C++

If the file names end in .c, they will be compiled as C. A C++ project even has a setting for selecting the C standard version.
